# Rxjs observable batch before execute

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I'm trying to build a function that get's an ID , Send it to server and return the response.
So far so good.. The issue is that this function may be called a lot of times, So I want to achieve the following:
Function get's an ID, Wait for 3 seconds and then execute. If another ID is been passed during those 3 seconds, append to to the ID's that were already sent and start the 3 seconds count again. After 3 seconds as pass, Send all ID's (In single request) and return the response to every ID sender.

So far I try to use Subject and the buffer operator :

```
  batchPlaceBetSubscription:Subject<string>=new Subject();
  batchPlaceBetSubscription:Observable<Response>;

  sendToServer(ID: string): Observable<any> {
    this.batchPlaceBetSubscription.next(ID);
    return this.batchPlaceBetSubscription$;

  }

  private placeBetBatchRequests(placeBetItem: IplaceBet[]) {
    this.batchPlaceBetSubscription$ = this.batchPlaceBetSubscription
      .buffer(Observable.timer(0, 3000))
      .take(1)
      .switchMap(IDsArray => {
        debugger;
        return this.http.post('http://someURL,IDsArray)
          .map(res => res.json())
          .catch(e => Observable.throw(e))
      })    
  }
```

This is almost work's but the first ID is been ignored (I guess because when the subject 'next' it, there are not subscribers yet).

So, How can I batch those ID's?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how `sendToServer` is called but you can use `ReplaySubject` for ` batchPlaceBetSubscription` that'll remeber items even when there's no subscriber.

Comment: sendToServer() is called from outside of this scope (From components). I thought of using replaySubject but how can I make sure it remembers all emited items, execute them and then clear it's memory for the next batch ?

Comment: Have you had a look at `debounceTime(3000)`? That restarts the 3 second timer but it would only emit the latest value so you would need to add another operator that appends the values.